# Inline stylesheet is not working when I convert HTML string to PDF using iText 5 .NET

Tags: c#, .net, itext, html-to-pdf, inline-styles

I have a problem here while converting an HTML string to pdf using iText 5 .NET and attaching the pdf byte array to mail attachment.

I am able to complete the above task without styling the table, means a mail will be triggered with pdf attached without css styles like below link

[image: Image of pdf what I got]

but the expected pdf table be like below link

![Img of Expected pdf][2]

I have used inline styles dynamically so, is there a way that I can get the expected result pdf with styles?

Below code is been used to convert the html string to pdf byte array

```
 public static byte[] HtmlToPdf(string sb) //here sb is the HTML string with inline styles
        {
            byte[] bytes;
           
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());

            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4_LANDSCAPE, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, memoryStream);
                pdfDoc.Open();

                htmlparser.Parse(new StringReader(sb));
                pdfDoc.Close();

                bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                memoryStream.Close();
            }
            return bytes;
        }
```

the byte used as an attachment in mail functionality

Comment: The `HTMLWorker` in iText 5 is considered deprecated (it's also marked `obsolete`). It was designed from the start to support only a minimal subset of HTML, so you should not use it for input which was not specifically created for this subset. In the context of iText 5 you should use the `XMLWorker` instead. An even better option is to use the pdfHTML converter in the iText 7 portfolio.